# Proxy FCGI error on a conflicted WordPress plugin

Tags: wordpress, apache, nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy, fastcgi

I'm using cwp panel

Creating a WordPress base website, but the problem when there's a conflicted plugin or you don't delete the plugin properly, it's cause 503 service unavailable. For example, this one:

```
[proxy_fcgi:error] [pid 313556:tid 139771011606272] [client 38.242.214.234:34910] AH01071: Got error 'PHP message: PHP Fatal error: Cannot redeclare checkLoad() (previously declared in /home/tmdbcom/others/themoviedb.com/wp-content/plugins/vidsrc_dooplay/inc/func.php:15) in /home/tmdbcom/others/themoviedb.com/wp-content/plugins/vidsrc_psyplay/vidsrc_psyplay.php on line 59', referer: https://themoviedb.com/wp-admin/update.php?action=upload-plugin
```

This is a log error. I got conflicted plugins, but when it's happened, the website is still working properly. Since there were conflicting plugins, I decided to delete both conflicting plugins.

But after some time, my website is down (503 service unavailable), and I checked the logs and got those error logs, and I need to restart Apache.

How do I solve this?